# How to iterate an ArrayList of object array using JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a list of object array like this.

```
List<Object[]> reqUserDetails = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Now I have to iterate this list and take values like Object[0],Object[1].... How can I do this using JSTL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general syntax is to itearate it like ,

```
<c:forEach items="${outerList}" var="innerList">
  <c:forEach items="${innerList}" var="item">
     // Print your object here
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

and in your case ,

```
<c:forEach items="${reqUserDetails}" var="firstVar"> 
      <c:forEach items="${firstVar}" var="secodVar"> // firstVar will hold your object array
         <c:out value="${secondVar.field1}" /> // on iterating the object array 
      </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
```

as it contains `array of objects` inside the `List` . so the outerList will hold the `Object[]` which you need to iterate again.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Can you please undo the down vote @SanKrish? I guess you did it and I have also updated my answer.

Comment: haha.. Okey.  I didn't notice his array of object at first time. :)

Answer (score 1):

From **controller**:

```
List<Object[]> reqUserDetails = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
request.setAttribute("reqUserDetails", reqUserDetails);
```

And from **view** side, you can iterate your list as per your requirement.

```
  <c:forEach items="${reqUserDetails}" var="objectList"> 
      <c:forEach items="${objectList}" var="object">
      <tr>
        <td>${object.field1}</td>
        <td>${object.field2}</td>
        <td>${object.field3}</td>
         ........
      </tr>
     </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: But how to iterate a list of object array (List<Object[]>)?

Comment: Warning !! His list contains `Array of objects` which shouldnt be iterated in this manner

Comment: Okey, @Usr1123, You can iterate again as per your requirement. It is something like for loop. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Why down vote @SanKrish? Haha, If he knows how to iterate list first then have can handle any kind of array or any level of list. I guess, You should comment here or can update this And it is so called "helping zone "

Comment: Dont feed direct code , help with some descriptions . which would help the OP .